# How Should I Use :root Pseudo Class?

Tags: html, css

When I use root (html element) in CSS for deciding display style of a web page, there is always some spaces around content even margin and padding are set by 0px. But when I use body element instead of root(html element), white space disappears. Should I use CSS on html (root) element   or CSS on body is enough?

Comment: `:root == <html>` but not `<body>`!

Comment: Is there any code you can share to help us understand the problem?

Comment: I understand what's the problem. I can't use HTML element for styling but I can use the body element. Thanks for the help. And how could I know that I should use body instead of HTML (so :root) unless I ask? Which is more suitable? I searched and couldn't find. Is asking a question here a sin?!

Answer (score 1):

[`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) matches the root element of a tree representing the document.

> In **HTML**, `:root` represents the `<html>` element

So if you have some default style on `<body>` and selecting `:root` makes no effect.

```css
html {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

:root {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

body {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
Inspect this snippet to see CSS applied
```